# Sequence multi-labelling with spaCy in Python

Tags: python, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am wondering whether it is possible to label a text where tokens may have several (overlapping) labels in NER task?

I would to learn car makes, however, I need to classify them as private or commercial cars.

For example:

```
text_0 = 'The new model of Mercedes is a great family car which also offers a space for home pets in the rear'

text_1 = 'It has been know for decades that Mercedes vehicle are very reliable for public transportation'
```

I need to extract the car make (which is easy and should give 'Mercedes'), however, I would like to also know in which context the car make has been mentioned. So the IE system should output:

```
text_0 -> (SYSTEM) -> {'car_make': 'Mercedes', 'vehicle_type': 'private'}

text_1 -> (SYSTEM) -> {'car_make': 'Mercedes', 'vehicle_type': 'commercial'}
```

**Potential solution**

I can annotate a large corpus to train a statistical model. So basically, I can train two separate NER models, one to identify car makes of a token and the second to label whether the same token is private/commercial.

The problem is how to combine both NER models, so their outputs will not overwrite entity tags. Is there a neat way to do it in spaCy?

Otherwise, please suggest how to add another attribute (private/commercial) to NER task of learning car makes.